# How can I render a variable in a git command inside Github Actions

Tags: github, github-actions

I am trying to get the version number inside my package.json file and use
the value as the tag number within my YAML file(Github Actions).

When I try to run the code:

```
- name: Get version number
  run: |
    node -p -e '`PACKAGE_VERSION=${require("./package.json").version}`' >> $GITHUB_ENV
    git tag -a "$PACKAGE_VERSION" -m "latest version"
```

I get this error `fatal: '' is not a valid tag name.`

I have also tried **git tag -a ${env.PACKAGE_VERSION} -m "latest version"** which also returns the error: `bad substitution`

What is the right way to render the **PACKAGE_VERSION** value inside the git command?

Answer (score 2):

You’re putting data into the GitHub Actions environment in the first line; this is data that’s part of the *Actions environment*, which is data that persists between steps.  It is not a *shell environment variable*, which is how you’re trying to reference the variable in the second line.

Since you’re just running two shell commands, just use shell environment variables.

```
- name: Get version number
  run: |
    export PACKAGE_VERSION=$(node -p -e 'require("./package.json").version')
    git tag -a "$PACKAGE_VERSION" -m "latest version"
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was that I separated the command for getting the package version from the rest of the commands:

So we have

```
- name: Get Package Version
  run: node -p -e '`PACKAGE_VERSION=${require("./package.json").version}`' >> $GITHUB_ENV
   
- name: Push Tag
  run: git tag -a $PACKAGE_VERSION -m "latest version"
```

The code above did the trick for me by separating the command for getting the package version from the git command.